# How to draw a parabola using basic equipment?

Tags: conic-sections, geometric-construction

A straight line can be drawn with a straightedge.
A circle can be drawn with a compass.
An ellipse can be drawn with [string and pins](https://www.mathopenref.com/printellipse1.html).

> How can we draw a [parabola](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Parabola.html), using basic equipment?

**Remarks**

The parabola should be "perfect" (like a circle drawn with a compass), not just a rough sketch. As far as how much of the parabola should be shown: enough so that it looks like a "U".

We can use basic equipment such as string, pins, etc. The simpler the equipment, the better (so for example, a method using an unmarked straightedge is better than a method using a marked straightedge). High tech tools like computers are not allowed. You are given paper, pen and a flat table.

We can define a parabola as the set of points in a plane equidistant to a fixed line (directrix) and a fixed point (focus), or use any equivalent definition.

I tried to find how the ancient Greeks physically drew parabolas, but found nothing.

Students at my school made an almost-perfect parabola using strings and pins, by setting strings such that for each string the sum of its $x$- and $y$- intercepts is $30$, so the strings are tangent to an envelope curve $\sqrt x + \sqrt y = \sqrt{30}$, which is a rotated parabola.

[image]

But this is not quite what I'm looking for, because it's not quite perfect, as the number of strings is finite.

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lVbfLlSLrZA) a carpenter shows how to make a beautiful almost-perfect parabola, similar to the string art above, but again it's not quite perfect because the number of lines is finite.

If it's not possible to draw a perfect parabola using basic equipment, then is there an explanation?

Comment: The "not drawn on paper" bit is easily fixed, you can use a straightedge and pen instead of strings. But I'll grant the rest :)

Comment: @hobbs Good point. I've edited.

Comment: After googling "draw parabola with string", and watching part of the youtube video at [Creating the Parabolic Curve with String](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r3xLqYYNp90), I surmise (perhaps wrongly) that what you want is impossible.  My surmise is based on the suspicion that if it was possible to attain a perfect parabola, the video would have shown that.

Comment: You can use a straightedge soaked with ink, and proceed with the strings-and-pins method, perhaps using some simple mechanisms to ensure the matching rate of sliding. This produces a "perfect" parabola, except that it also colors one side of it completely black.

Comment: Look at Cor. 2 here: https://archive.org/details/cu31924031271509/page/n11/mode/1up Is that fine for you?

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Yes, that's what I was looking for! Feel free to make your comment into an answer. Alternatively, I can do so.

Comment: Do write an answer if you like, I'm not going to do it.

Comment: Your picture doesn't show parabolas. They are circle quarters.

Comment: They may look like quarter circles, but actually they are part of a rotated parabola. In the lower-left quarter of the square, (most of) the strings are such that the sum of the $x$- and $y$- intercepts is $30$. This implies that the strings are tangent to the envelope curve $\sqrt x + \sqrt y = \sqrt{30}$, which is a rotated parabola.

Comment: Oh, you are right. If we put 5 intersection points of the set of lines from, say, the lower-left quarter into the conic section general equation and do the calculations we will have the equation of a parabola (which can be tangent to the equation of circle too)

Comment: [slightly facetious] Maybe you could hold the paper vertically and throw the pen in the air next to it to form a parabolic arc on the paper...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lNSIGxImgeA) is video of a brilliant "conic section compass".

[Here](https://www.instructables.com/The-Lost-Art-of-the-Conic-Section-Compass/) is a closer look at how it works. It is very simple: the axis of the compass is the axis of a cone. The pencil is a slanting "edge" of the cone. The axis of the cone, and the axis of the pencil, intersect at the vertex of the cone. The paper is a plane intersecting the cone. The pencil traces the intersection of the plane and the cone - literally, a conic section.

Answer (score 2):

From the comments, @Intelligentipauca found [A Geometrical Treatise on Conic Sections](https://archive.org/details/cu31924031271509/page/n11/mode/1up). Page 4 shows:

[image]

This is exactly what I was looking for.

### Extension to hyperbola

This approach could also be used to draw a hyperbola.

[image]

The bar is shown in red, the string is shown in green (the string covers part of the bar). Note that the bar is longer than the string by a certain length. The bar and string are connected on the right.

The left end of the bar pivots around the left focus point. The other end of the string is attached to the right focus point.

The pen is fixed to a sliding point on the bar. As the bar pivots, the string is kept taut by the pen (a rubber band connecting the left left focus point and the tip of the pen would do the trick).

As the bar pivots, the pen traces a hyperbola. As the bar pivots, the gradient of the bar approaches the gradient of the asymptote of the hyperbola. (To draw more of the hyperbola, get a longer bar and string.)

### Ancient Greeks

After I posted my question, I found that, according to the bottom of page 2 of a [book](https://core.ac.uk/reader/56371070) on conic sections, the ancient Greeks "were not able to construct conics in the plane". I guess they would not have fancied the method of construction described above.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done if your "basic equipment" includes a contraption that
allows a triple of concurrent lines (say, rods) to slide freely while
retaining the concurrence.  The key mathematical tool is Pascal's
theorem, or more precisely its converse, known as
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braikenridge%E2%80%93Maclaurin_theorem.

> The Braikenridge-Maclaurin theorem may be applied in the
> Braikenridge-Maclaurin construction, which is a synthetic construction
> of the conic defined by five points, by varying the sixth
> point. Namely, Pascal's theorem states that given six points on a
> conic (the vertices of a hexagon), the lines defined by opposite sides
> intersect in three collinear points. This can be reversed to construct
> the possible locations for a sixth point, given five existing ones.

This result allows one to construct, using a ruler only, an arbitrary
point on a conic section passing through given 5 points.  If one
chooses the five points so that the resulting conic will be a
parabola, this gives a way of constructing a parabola, in the
following sense: given an arbitrary line $\ell$ through A, one
constructs the point on $x$ which lies on the conic.

Thus, if one starts for example with the five points $(0,0)$, $(1,1)$,
$(-1,1)$, $(2,4)$, $(-2, 4)$, one will obtain as output the standard
parabola $y=x^2$.

There is a nice animation here for the case of the parabola:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_points_determine_a_conic#Construction

Answer (score 0):

You can define the parabola as an envelope of lines. Start with the focus $F$ and directrix line $l$. Select points $P_k$ on $l$ and construct the perpendicular bisector $m_k$ between $F$ and each $P_k$.

At any point on $m_k$ for each $k$, the distance to $F$ is equal to the distance to $P_k$. But the distance from a point on $m_k$ to $l$ as a whole is less except at one point where $m_k$ meets the perpendicukar to $l$ from $P_k$. Thus $m_k$ is tangent to the parabola for all $k$ and the parabola is defind as the envelope of all tge perpendicular bisectors.

As with other envelope curves, you can realize this definition with good accuracy by constructing perpendicular bisectors to a sufficiently close-packed set of directrix points $P_k$.