# There is a compass-like tool that can draw $y=x^2$ on paper. Is there one for $y=x^3$?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, curves, cubics, geometric-construction

Is there a tool that can draw $y=x^3$ on paper?

I'm referring to low-tech tools, e.g. not computers.

I only know of tools that can draw $y=x^2$. The YouTube video ["Conic Sections Compass"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lNSIGxImgeA) from khosrowsadeghi shows one; the Instructables entry ["The Lost Art of the Conic Section Compass"](https://www.instructables.com/The-Lost-Art-of-the-Conic-Section-Compass/) by hombremagnetico gives a closer look. It is very simple. The axis of the "compass" is the axis of a cone, the pencil is a slanting "edge" of the cone, and the paper is a plane. The pencil traces the intersection of the plane and the cone - literally, a conic section.

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4817777/398708) to my previous question ["How to draw a parabola using basic equipment?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4817250/409), I show another tool, as described in ["A Geometrical Treatise on Conic Sections" (via archive.org)](https://archive.org/details/cu31924031271509/page/n11/mode/1up) by W. H. Drew, that draws $y=x^2$.

I am looking for a tool that can draw $y=x^3$. It would surely exploit some property of the curve $y=x^3$. But how?

Comment: This [paper](https://ecommons.cornell.edu/server/api/core/bitstreams/a9783fdf-8167-47ef-8fd4-2561fd2ede00/content) may be useful.

Comment: Apparently it's possible to solve cubics with origami, might be able to adapt that into a mechanism of some kind.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AaH89XS3lwI